Is the boundary of a box a smooth manifold?
Consider the (topological) boundary $\partial B$ of a box $B=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is $\partial B$ a smooth $1$-manifold? The sharp edges point intuitively to a negative answer, yet I'm struggling to prove this.
